# tkinter hangman Button

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I have .txt file with words I entered myself, the program however does allow you to enter your own word. What seems to be the problem is that when I click a button it doesn't recognise it as a guess at the word, i realise this code is far from complete but any help would be much appreciated P.S. if you could also let me know how to get the entry feild above the keyboard that would be great :D

```
from tkinter import*

import time
import random

root= Tk()
top = Tk()


top.title('Hangmanz') 
top.geometry('500x140')

root.geometry('200x250')
root.title('Photo')




def appear(index, letter):
    # This line would be where you insert the letter in the textbox
    guess = ('')
    guess += str(letter)
    if letter in line:
        print(char,end=''),



    # set the players guess to guesses







    w.insert(0,letter)

    # Disable the button by index
    buttons[index].config(state="disabled")







letters=["Q", "A", "Z", "W", "S", "X", "E", "D", "C", "R", "F", "V", "T", "G", "B",
         "Y", "H", "N", "U", "J", "M", "I", "K", "O", "L", "P"]

# A collection (list) to hold the references to the buttons created below
buttons = []

for index in range(26): 
    n=letters[index]

    button = Button(top, bg="White", text=n, width=5, height=1, relief=GROOVE,
                    command=lambda index=index, n=n: appear(index, n))

    # Add the button to the window
    button.grid(padx=2, pady=2, row=index%3, column=index//3)

    # Add a reference to the button to 'buttons'
    buttons.append(button)

w = Entry(root,width=22, fg="black",
bg="#f2f2f2", font="Impact")
w.pack()



#photo   
canvas = Canvas(root,width = 200, height = 200, bg = 'white')
canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
gif1 = PhotoImage(file = 'Scaffold01.gif')
canvas.create_image(50, 10, image = gif1, anchor = NW)

ok=True
while ok==True:
    answer = input ("Would you like to input a new word? Enter Y or N ")

    if answer == ('Y'):
        file = open("Hangmanwords.txt", "a")
        d =input("enter new word ")
        file.write("\n"+d)
        file.close()
        c=input("would you like to add another word? Y or N")
        if c == ('y'):
            ok=True
        elif c == ('N'):
            ok=False
    elif answer == ('N'):
            ok=False
time.sleep(1)
print("Get ready to play!")



line = random.choice(open("Hangmanwords.txt","r").readlines())
print(line)

for char in line:
        print("*")





root.mainloop()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: There are too many fundamental problems with this code: you shouldn't use `input` with `Tkinter`, you shouldn't ever call `time.sleep` in a GUI, you shouldn't have an infinite loop other than the event loop, you shouldn't call `mainloop` twice.

Answer (score -2):

As I am not very good at Python, I can't spot your error/ how to fix it but I can answer your question on how to make an entry box:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
def receiveVar:
    x=var.get()
    #What you want to do with the variable goes here
var=StringVar()
mentry=Entry(root,textvariable=var).pack()
btn=Button(root,text='Ok',command=receiveVar).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You created a bad example: `mentry` and `btn` will always be set to `None` -- a common beginner mistake that people ask about all the time on this site. A good answer shouldn't make this sort of common error because it helps propagate a bad style of programming.